# Contact form not responding

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I'm trying to implement a basic contact form for my website that comprises of three fields: Name, Email and Message. The php code I'm working with is given below:

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name2'];
$email = $_POST['email2'];
$message = $_POST['message2'];

$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.

// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{
        $subject = $name;
        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
        $headers .= 'Cc:' . $email. "\r\n"; // Carbon copy to Sender
        $template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:white;">Hello ' . $name . ',<br/>'
        . '<br/>Thank you for contacting me!<br/><br/>'
        . 'Name:' . $name . '<br/>'
        . 'Email:' . $email . '<br/>'
        . 'Message:' . $message . '<br/><br/>'
        . 'This is a Contact Confirmation mail.'
        . '<br/>'
        . 'I\'ll get back to you as soon as possible .</div>';
        $sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#7E7E7E; color:white;\">" . $template . "</div>";
        // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
        $sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);
        // Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
        mail("myemailid@gmail.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
        echo "Your message has been sent successfully!";
} 
else 
{
    echo "<span>* invalid email *</span>";
}
?>
```

(obviously I replaced myemailid@gmail.com with my actual email address)

The JavaScript file calling this php code is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name2").val();
var email = $("#email2").val();
var message = $("#message2").val();

// Checking for blank fields.
if (name == '' || email == '' || message == '') 
{
    alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
} 
else 
{
    $.post("contact_form.php", 
    {
        name2: name,
        email2: email,
        message2: message,
    }, function(data) {

    if (data == "Your message has been sent successfully!") {
    $("#footer-form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
    }
    });
}
});
});
```

When I click the 'Send' button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

In case this helps:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="footer-content">
                                <form role="form" id="footer-form">
                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="name2">Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" placeholder="Name" name="name2" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="email2">Email address</label>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" placeholder="Enter email" name="email2" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="message2">Message</label>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="message2" placeholder="Message" name="message2" required></textarea>
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Also, the php URL I would get on clicking the Send button was as under:

```
/index.html?name2=John+Doe&email2=johndoe%40example.com&message2=This+is+a+test+message.
```

Ever since I changed the button type to 'button' instead of 'submit', the button doesn't reload the page or give me this URL.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your browser debugger tools to see what response you're getting?

Comment: fetching values from URL with `$_POST` i think should be `$_GET`

Comment: @shehary he is using `$.post` so that probably isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is an syntax error, the `}` after the `echo "Your message has been sent successfully!";`.

**EDIT:**

Moreover, make sure to verify if `$("#submit").click` is called.

You also need to cancel the form submit action (you're using ajax to send the mail).

Comment: Ok so I fixed the extra } (thanks for pointing that out!). But changing the POST method to GET doesn't help!

Comment: @DarthCoder I never said to change the method ! xD Keep the POST method. Can you show us the view ? please

Comment: Oh ok. So here's the problem. Earlier I had the button type to 'submit' and it would show me the php-url. Since, I changed it to type button instead, the page doesn't reload and give me a url. I've added the original url to the question description.

Comment: @DarthCoder Do you have still an issue ?

Comment: Yes I still have the issue. Did you remove the code you posted earlier? How do I cancel the form submit action?

Comment: @DarthCoder When you use `<input type="button" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default">` the form is normally not submitted.  That's why i removed my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83609/discussion-between-zilongqiu-and-darth-coder).

Answer (score 0):

To read form params in your PHP you need to use $_GET. Debug at that level. See if you're getting those values on your server side. Also, make sure you're reading all the values in js. Providing your HTML chunk would help.

Comment: You also have an extra "}" in your PHP code, as zilongqiu noted.

Comment: As mentioned by @MrMadsen, [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) load data from the server using a HTTP POST request. So the `$_GET` is not the problem.

Comment: I tried replacing POST with GET but it still doesn't work. Also, I check the values in the JS script and they are fine.

Comment: @zilongqiu check the url given by the OP it's definetly a GET

Comment: @user3980820 DarthCoder want to send the mail with an ajax request and he is using $.post. The GET happened because he used a input type submit (+ form tag send by default with GET method if submitted) instead of a button. So the form was submitted and he was redirected.